# JAVA & MySQL unwanted extra column

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, phpmyadmin

So basically I have created a database with a single table inside(just for testing purposes), having 2 elements (first VARCHAR(255) and age INTEGER) like this:

```
protected void createTableExamPeriod() throws SQLException {
    //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating table in given database...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();

      String drop = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS REGISTRATION ";
      String table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS REGISTRATION " +
                   " (first VARCHAR(255), " + 
                   " age INTEGER )"; 

      stmt.executeUpdate(drop);
      stmt.executeUpdate(table);
      populateExamPeriodTable();
      System.out.println("Created table in given database...");
}
```

But when I look inside my database, there is an extra column, called 'New' :
[image]

So my question is, how do I get rid of this extra column, as right now, I can't insert the 'correct' number of arguments inside it, because of this extra column, when I do:

```
protected void populateExamPeriodTable() throws SQLException {
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String insertSql = "INSERT REGISTRATION VALUES(3 + 2 + 5)";

    stmt.executeUpdate(insertSql);
}
```

Comment: Your `INSERT` statement doesn't work because you only supplied **1** value, and that table has two columns. With your `INSERT`, what value would you expect column `first` to have?

Comment: `3 + 2 + 5` is an expression that evaluates to `10`, so you're saying `INSERT REGISTRATION VALUES(10)`. Multiple values must be separated by comma (`,`), and your first value should be a string literal, since the column is `VARCHAR`, which means you should use: `INSERT REGISTRATION VALUES('Hello', 10)`

Comment: Thank you! I've changed it now! Much appreciated everyone! Have a good day! :)

Answer (score 3):

`New` is not a new column `PHPMyAdmin` shows it to add a new column graphically

Comment: I just tried changing the:
String insertSql = "INSERT REGISTRATION VALUES(2 + 5)";

So I had 2, in stead of 3 values, but it still gave me the

Column count doesn't match  value count at row 1

It can't be that, but makes sense to be!
Thank you for your answer

Comment: @user3153278 That `INSERT` statement only has **one** value. `2 + 5` equals `7`, so you're saying `INSERT REGISTRATION VALUES(7)`.

Comment: @user3153278 your sql statement requires a string and a integer ,(2 + 5)  gives only one value

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of this extra column, as right now, you can drop the column and create a valid code to create table with the *correct* number of arguments inside it, because of this extra column is redundant:

```
alter table registration drop column `New`;
create table registration (first VARCHAR(255), age INT);
```